# Argument labels do not match any available overloads [sprite.physicsBody?.vector = CGVector()]

Tags: swift, sprite, physics

Okay. I am trying to code a rendition of Flappy Bird using my own sprites for fun and learning. I have been implementing physics and now am trying to apply impulses and define velocities to some physics bodies. I know the physics is working because my ghost sprite falls to the ground, however I am having some issues implementing velocity and impulses to the ghost sprite (to make it jump up and fall down again).

Here is my code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    Ghost.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(0, 0)
    Ghost.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(0, 90))

}
```

I am receiving errors on the two lines where I use CGVector. I believe in earlier versions of swift this was CGVectorMake. The errors read:

```
Argument labels '(_, _)' do not match any available overloads
```

I'm really not sure what this means or how to go about fixing this. If necessary I can link more of the code but it's quite lengthy. I appreciate any advice or tips. This is using the latest swift and Xcode to date. Xcode 9.0 and Swift 4.0.3.

Comment: Why don't you use XCode's [autocompletion](https://image.prntscr.com/image/nB7hMYjLS9aMSQ27zpSYEg.png)? It would clearly show you that what you are looking for is `CGVector(dx:,dy:)`.

Comment: the auto completion did not yield this for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation for CGVector](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgvector), I see constructors of the form:

```
init(dx: Double, dy: Double)
```

This means that instead of typing `CGVector(0, 0)`, you'd need something like `CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)`.

For future reference, when you see a label that is an underscore, it generally means "no label" — you'd look for argument values that you passed without a preceding name, and add a name that the API expects.

Comment: Thank you, this cleared it right up. I did reference the API however I am still new to all this and sometimes what I read in the API is difficult to wrap my head around

Answer (score 0):

Your `CGVector` init is missing the argument labels.  You can fix by changing to

```
CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 90)
```

For reference, take a look at apple docs for these kinds of errors: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgvector